# Values out of named (with years) rows

Tags: r

This is my code:

```
num <- as.matrix(1:10)
rownames(num) <- c(2001:2010)
num["2005",]
```

This works. Why does `num["2005":"2007",]` not work? I want the values from the named rows 2005 to 2007. I know it would work with ts objects but sometimes I have to control my series and then its more comfortable when the rows are named by years. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `"2005":"2007"`. R internally converts this into integer and then building the array out of them:

```
> typeof("2005":"2007")
[1] "integer"
```

Therefore you can just convert this into character:

```
> num[as.character("2005":"2007"), ]
2005 2006 2007 
   5    6    7
```

Comment: Good point. Other option could be `num[paste("2005":"2007"),]`

Comment: Aaah! Perfect thanks a lot! This knowledge makes a lot of things easier.